# good tutorial for Ruby - RGL library

Tags: rubygems

I am struggling lot to program using rgl library methods. Can anyone tell good source to rgl. Except this http://rgl.rubyforge.org.

Comment: http://scs.math.yorku.ca/index.php/MATH_6627_2012-13_Practicum_in_Statistical_Consulting/R_tutorials/rgl_tutorial

Comment: not the same rgl. The poster's asking about the Ruby Graph Library, your link is a R 3D graphics package

Comment: You can find this useful http://www.rubydoc.info/github/monora/rgl

Answer (score 0):

this one looks good http://rubydoc.info/gems/rgl/0.4.0/frames , at least better then your rubyforge one